# Multiple conditions for a FilterExpression

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, query-expressions

I am using Condition expression but I'm unable to add more than one condition to a `FilterExpression`.
Can any one help? I have posted my source code here.

ConditionExpression with Filters:

```
  // Filter1
FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression();
filter1.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("A_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id1));
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("B_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id2));
query.Criteria.Filters.Add(filter1);
```

// Filter2

```
FilterExpression filter2 = new FilterExpression();
filter2.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("B_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id3));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("C_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id4));
q_ShoppingCartItemQuantityCheck.Criteria.Filters.Add(filter2);
```

Comment: When it comes to more complex expressions, I found out that I have hard time setting them up the way you did. It's doable but not as transparent as the initializer approach. When I get to work in an hour, I'll post an alternative example for you. Hopefully it'll be more expandable for you. (Also, you need to accept one of the answers - mine will be of course the best one, haha.)

Answer (score 25):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. 
If I got it right, you want to build a hierarchical expression like this:

> (A_logicalName AND B_LogicalName) OR (B_LogicalName AND
>   C_LogicalName)

is that correct?

Wouldn't the following then solve your problem?

```
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression(); 
query.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;

FilterExpression filter1 = query.Criteria.AddFilter(LogicalOperator.And);
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("A_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id1));
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("B_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id2));

FilterExpression filter2 = query.Criteria.AddFilter(LogicalOperator.And);
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("B_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id2));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("C_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id3));
```

See also example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309410.aspx).

Comment: any ***Fluent*** helper version about it?

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I'm using. For some reason, I find it clearer to grasp. It's probably due to the fact that I use initializer syntax so YMMV.

```
...
Criteria = new FilterExpression
{
  FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or,
  Filters =
  {
    new FilterExpression
    {
      FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
      Conditions =
      {
        new ConditionExpression("field1", ConditionOperator.NotNull),
        new ConditionExpression("field2", ConditionOperator.NotNull)
      }
    },
    new FilterExpression
    {
      FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
      Conditions =
      {
        new ConditionExpression("field3", ConditionOperator.NotNull),
        new ConditionExpression("field4", ConditionOperator.NotNull)
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: I find that *much* better than anything else I have seen

Answer (score 11):

Condition:

```
(A_logicalName AND B_LogicalName) OR (B_LogicalName AND C_LogicalName)
```

can be expressed in this way too:

```
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);

FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("A_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id1));
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("B_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id2));

FilterExpression filter2 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("B_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id2));
filter2.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("C_LogicalName", ConditionOperator.Equal, id3));

filter.AddFilter(filter1);
filter.AddFilter(filter2);

query.Criteria = filter;
```

A more complex query can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.queryexpression.aspx).